# Oracle PL/SQL get server's IP v4?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

How can I get the IP v4 Of the server by using PL/SQL ? `UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS` gives me IPv6, while I need IPv4

what I did I disabled the IPv6 on the sever, still it's bringing me the the IPv6 of the "Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface" !!

I'm using Oracle 11g database on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Comment: Using 10g it returns IPv4 address for me, but I don't think we have IPv6 included.

Comment: i'm using 11g on windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS` returns just an ip which is nonsense since a server may have dozens of them. Probably your best bet it's to create a pl/sql wrapper of a Java method which returns every possible ip address using `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();`

Comment: the server we are setting up has one IP, so it's ok if it returns this one IP!

Comment: It seems that's not  true when you have ipv6 interfaces. You could open an ipv4 connection with utl_tcp (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_tcp2.htm#1002748)and look at the local_host property, but I don't think its a great idea...

Comment: This may also work:  select UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SERVER
_HOST')) ipaddr from dual;