# Command to show IP address in Oracle 10g R2?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, ip-address

I have been searching online and only found commands to retrieve the hostname.

As far as I can make out there is no reverse-resolution mechanism within Oracle itself; it relies on DNS, HOST records or its own Net Management.

Is it possible to return the database server's local IP address from an SQL command?

Comment: Why not using usual DNS request?

Comment: Server can have more then one IPs, so call to `UTL_INADDDR` may produce unexpected results. Please review [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267905/oracle-pl-sql-get-servers-ip-v4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address from dual;

GET_HOST_ADDRESS
----------------------------------
192.168.2.5
```

Following URL would be helpful:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/identifying-host-names-and-addresses.php